# How can I throttle file downloads with WebBrowser?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

I'm trying to limit file download a file at a time using `System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser` or `System.Windows.Controls.WebBrowser`. 
I try to catch this at `System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser.FileDowload` event, but can't know when the file is completely downloaded.
Is there any way to catch when is the file download completed at `Windows.Forms.WebBrowser` or `Windows.Controls.WebBrowser`.
Thanks.

```
    void descargaCompleta(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        // When the download is complete
        descargando = false;
    }

    void solo1Descarga (object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser web = (System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser)sender;

        // Ask for Mutex
        descargas.WaitOne();

        descargando = true;

        while (descargando)
            ;

        descargas.ReleaseMutex();
    }

    // Función que Modifica la GUI
    private void UpadteTabs()
    {
        WindowsFormsHost contWeb = new WindowsFormsHost();
        System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser nav = new System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser();
        // I set the Events to WebBrowser
        nav.FileDownload += new EventHandler (solo1Descarga);
        nav.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler (descargaCompleta);
    }
```

Note: "download a file at a time" means that a download single can be at the same time.
For example, if you are trying to download a mega file and an image, 1 of the files needs to wait to the other finish

Comment: please show us some code you have tried so far.

Comment: This are the events that I'm using. 
I am using WPF, but the WebBrowser is from System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser. 
The reason is that I think that from those I can control the downloads.

I want to know when the download is completed.

https://gist.github.com/iraskato/ae5347a2e7c5c550c6091dfbcf5d37bb

Comment: @Iraskato What does `download a file at a time` mean? Just *don't* issue a new download before the previous finishes.

Comment: @Iraskato post your code and explanations in the question itself, not some other place which can disappear at any time. Post ONLY relevant code, not the entire form.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes "download a file at a time" means that a download single can be at the same time.
For example, if you are trying to download a mega file and an image, 1 of the files needs to wait to the other finish

Answer (score 0):

You can use `WebReponse` to download file

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(fileUri);
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
DownLoadFile(response, response.ContentLength);

private void DownLoadFile(HttpWebResponse response, long contentLength)
{
    var respContentType = response.ContentType.ToUpper();
    using (var fileStream = File.OpenWrite(fileName))
    {
        using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
        {
            var buffer = new byte[1024];

            int bytesRead;
            int offset = 0;

            //Thread.Sleep(100);
            while ((bytesRead = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
            {
                fileStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                offset += bytesRead;
            }

            if (offset != response.ContentLength)
            {
                //return string.Format("Only downloaded {0} of {1} bytes", offset, response.ContentLength));
                throw new ApplicationException(string.Format("Only downloaded {0} of {1} bytes",
                                                    offset, response.ContentLength));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Alternativly write a while loop to read the binary data

```
public void DownloadFile(Uri uri, string filePathToSave)
{   
    var downloadedData = webClient.DownloadData(uri);
    while (downloadedData.Length == 0)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        downloadedData = webClient.DownloadData(uri);
    }
    Stream file = File.Open(filePathToSave, FileMode.Create);
    file.Write(downloadedData, 0, downloadedData.Length);
    file.Close();
}
```